# Is it possible to reimage windows and keep all installed programs, but no users profile?

Tags: windows, disk-image

Is it possible to reimage windows 10 as new and keep all current installed apps?

Expected Result: When the new image deployed to the machine and user bootup, it ask user to create account. Once logged in, all their needed apps are already installed.

Comment: You should edit your question instead of submitting a comment.  Having applications already installed requires you to create a windows image yourself.  What part of that process are you stuck on exactly?  Be as specific as possible.  We will be unable to document the entire process for you in an answer.

Comment: The computer is ready to be backup as it already have the applications installed. I just wanted to backup Windows with all of the installed programs. However, I would like to wipe out the user profiles so when I image a new machine; it would ask the user to create their account.

Comment: If you use sysrep that is built into W10 it will generalize your custom installation, now shut down and image the disk offline, when done imaging boot back into windows, it will ask you to set up a new user, basically an OOBE setup>>>>>>>>https://www.petri.com/using-syspre-windows-10

Comment: @JohnHang - What have you tried?